# jboss log rotation

Tags: logging, jboss, rotation

I'm deployment engineer, our company use jboss as an application server so we have lot of development team environment. Check jboss log file and remove unnecessary log is time consuming task. Is there any method to log file rotation? We have window as an OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a bit of googling you can find the answer on your own. Whatever, the native logging libraries included in JBoss allow you to configure rotating log files (you can define how many log files you want to keep, and the maximum size of the files), so what you're asking is quite straightforward.

If you're using Jboss 3.x/4.x/5.x look for the log4j appender (configured in conf/jboss-log4j.xml):

- [org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender](http://java.dzone.com/articles/configuring-logging-jboss).

On the other hand if you're using JBoss 7.x, since it doesn't use log4j anymore, you can use the [size-rotating-file-handler](https://community.jboss.org/message/759283) (configured in configuration/standalone.xml or configuration/domain.xml)